# How to recognize version of 802.11 standard in beacon-frame?

Tags: wifi, wireshark

I need to recognize supported 802.11 standards and distinguish **a,b,g,n,ac ** of AP's only by reading Beacon-frames. Is there specific subfields from beacon-frame, that signed that AP uses certain standards? Is there table with differences of this standards?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M2tS.png)

I used wireshark with wifi-adapter in monitor mode, but i see a lot of subfields in beacon frames